# How to prove a ring and a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is my process correct. Is there a better way? Are there any mistakes?

[image][image]

Above, I don't know how to prove in blue color.

The next question was, to show if it is also a field:

[image]

Comment: Kindly use mathjax to format your questions

Comment: @PankajTiwari , sorry just bought my ipad and wanted to give it a try on the site

Comment: @BiliDebili And it comes out looking awful :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your work is correct.

The proof of the commutativity of multiplication is easier if you note that
$$
a \otimes b = e^{\ln(a)\ln(b)}.
$$

---

A bit of overkill: this definition of $\oplus, \otimes$ is simply a [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure). In particular, if we define $\phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R_+$ by $\phi(x) = e^x$, then we have
$$
a \oplus b = \phi(\phi^{-1}(a) + \phi^{-1}(b)), \quad 
a \otimes b = \phi(\phi^{-1}(a) \times \phi^{-1}(b)).
$$

Comment: IMHO it is not overkill at all. Providing this isomorphism is the easiest way to prove all these properties by just citing them for $(\mathbb R, +, \times)$.