# How to prove that a ring is isomorphic to another ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I don't know if I have done the correct process to prove for homomorphism, is it correct?

How to prove for isomorphism (so if the homomorphism was correct, how to prove bijection).

Comment: You haven't even defined your proposed homomorphism.

Comment: Use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597913/corresponding-isomorphism-real-number) with exponentiation. Then conclude for logarithm - see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789561/how-to-prove-a-ring-and-a-field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that two rings are isomorphic, you need to give an example of an isomorphism between the two rings. That is, it is not enough to simply write $f(a \oplus b) = f(a) + f(b)$, you need to say what the function $f$ does.  That is, you need to write something of the form $f(x) = ???$.